# How to provide a button which will change my current page content to an previous page in drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm making a site wherein I want to show the current course that I'm gonna teach to my pupils.In this page there should also be links provided to my previous courses. Now when I'm done with this course I want to transfer it to a previous course or rather automatically create a link for it and get the new course content in it's place. I just think doing manually is kind of stupid. Rather I want to have a form where i can create my new course then click on make current course as previous and this course as new whenever i wish.How can I do this.Is this even possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty open question ... One way would be to work with views when showing a node.

In the view you should use a [custom php field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield), which collects the record (nid) within the course-node table. And then create a link using the drupal path_alias function  or by using node/nid ...

---

You could use [panels-module](http://drupal.org/project/panels) as well. Where you have a view with the latest course, and under the latest course you have a view of a link to the latest course -1 . (I think you can set an offset in views to get the previous course) The view should accept an argument, namely the nid of the currently loaded node.

If you use this method, do check if your panels is giving the arguments to the views module.

---

Another way would be to use node reference as to what is the previous course (but you don't want it to be manual). The advantage of node_reference is that you don't need to enter your courses in a certain order. If you make it automatically, then the order in which you fill in the courses should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Easy man. Just create a content type called "course" and using [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck), add all the fields to capture information you want about the course.

Now you have the content. Using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), create a simple view page displaying course content type and sort it on descending order, set it to display one item at a time and add a mini pager. That way the new course will be the first one displayed and the other ones will be behind it. You might need to customize the pager a bit ^^